# Microsoft Acess Sum IIf Expression

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to figure out how to count the total entries that contain a specific value among multiple values. So, for example, the field contains one or more codes (i.e. I, A, B, P) and I'm trying to find all the entries that contain a code of I regardless of any other codes also in there. The expression I tried is `=Sum(IIf([Risk] Like "I",1,0))`, but it will only show the total number of entries that ONLY contain I. It will not add in those fields that contain multiple codes such as I / A / P. Is there a way to modify this expression to include all entries that have a code of I regardless of any other codes mixed in?

An example of my current report results would be:

> I
>
> I
>
> I / A
>
> I / A / B
>
> I
>
> I / B

`=Sum(IIf([Risk] Like "I",1,0))` will return a total value of 3 entries instead of the proper 6 entries

Comment: This could be more read-friendly formated, please read formatting help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: LIKE without wildcard might as well just be =. `=Sum(IIf([Risk] Like "I*",1,0))`